# First task inside a sequence container - need to check several variables before executing

Tags: ssis

I want to check the values of several variables before executing a sql task. The sql task is the 1st task within a container.  Since there is no direct task before this one, I have no constraint to put an expression on.  What could be used in this case?

Comment: what is version of SSIS?

Comment: Version is SSIS 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If version  of SSIS is 2012+, then Expression Task is to be added as a predecessor of SQL Task.

In other cases you can just add a dummy SQL task with something like SELECT 0 and setup then some expression on a constraint between that dummy and SQL tasks.

Alternative approach: you pass variables into SQL task and perform validation there:

```
DECLARE @_param1 VARCHAR(50) = ?
DECLARE @_param2 VARCHAR(50) = ?

IF @_param1 = 0 AND @_param2 = 0  -- check variables values
RETURN
ELSE 
BEGIN
    -- your SQL code
END
```

Comment: SSIS 2014, Yes, I had considered an expression task, but was hoping I could simply use an expression to check the value of these variables, rather than setting a new variable to the results of checking the primary variables involved.